# Anything I can do about getting SSSS twice in a row for an international flight?

Tags: usa, air-travel

When trying to check in for a Delta flight today, I've received the following message:

> Unfortunately, government regulations require you check in at the airport, either at the kiosk or with an agent, for this flight.

As per a thread found on FlyerTalk, this means I've got Secondary Security Screening Selection (SSSS). This is the second time in a row, as I've previously received it on an international flight to the US back in May. I'm a Global Entry member and a Green Card holder, plus recently pre-approved for Nexus so definitely not on any government lists. Is there something I can do to minimize my odds of getting SSSS again?

Comment: For what it's worth, I flew Delta last month, received that message when I tried to check in online, and did not have to do the SSSS procedure.  The issue had something to do with it being a US-to-Canada flight and them needing to verify my passport in person.  (I think. It was 4 AM and the airport was packed for some reason so I wasn't too inclined to ask probing follow-up questions at the time.)

Comment: Getting a redress number through [DHS TRIP](https://www.dhs.gov/dhs-trip) made the SSSS'ing stop for me when I was getting it on a semi-regular basis, though it's an extremely opaque process so there's no real guarantee it will work. Worth a shot though.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert was SSSS after all. Not a big deal, just annoying since I couldn't use online check in.

Comment: In theory, SSSS is entirely random (though that doesn't seem to be the case in practice), so I doubt anyone will admit there's a way to make it less likely. (Also, allowing people to game the system in that way would inherently harm any supposed utility of the program.)

Comment: @AR-solidarityforModstrike the program is pure security theater unfortunately as anyone with devious plans is warned about the extra security checks long in advance...

Comment: @JonathanReez-onstrike I don't doubt it, but to maintain the theater they have to act like it does something, and allowing people to bypass it would go against that interest.